# Is gdal 2.1 is available for windows?

Tags: gdal, windows, wmts

I would try Gdal 2.1, does someone knows if it is available for windows ? 
For example I would try those WMTS features :
http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wmts.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a GDAL 2.1.0 development version available at http://www.gisinternals.com/development.php

If you carefully look for the compiling date, you see that the MSVC 2008 and 2010 builds are the newest ones. If you follow the [information](http://www.gisinternals.com/packageinfo.php?file=release-1500-gdal-mapserver.zip) link of those , you see

```
The compiled GDAL reports the following version information. (gdalinfo --version)
GDAL 2.1.0dev, released 2015/99/99
```

Comment: thanks I didn't look here. that's what I looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Tamas Szekeres maintains GDAL development packages which are compiled daily based on the current GDAL development sourcecode. The current dev release is `GDAL 2.1.0dev`.

[GDAL development packages](http://www.gisinternals.com/development.php)

These are mainly for testing purposes and might not work as expected, but your mileage may vary.